# Will fire destroy white walkers or just the wights?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

It is clearly said in the *Game of Thrones* series that fire destroys wights.

Also it is known that dragonglass and valyrian steel can destroy both wights and white walkers.

Can white walkers also be destroyed by fire like the wights?

Answer (score 15):

We know that normal fire does not affect them. They are seen walking right through the fire created by the children to shield the cave from the incoming wights, and the fire appears to extinguish before them. We also see the White Walker that Jon kills walk into a burning building, seemingly unfazed.

[image: White Walker entering a burning building]

It is not clear whether they can be destroyed by dragonfire.

Comment: On your last statement, I think it is safe to assume that they are.  After the battle of Hardhome, and all the soldiers that were killed from both sides seemed to have been rezzed again in a taunt as jon snow looked on.  I would imagine with the amount of masses that the dragons killed, a huge demoralization factor would to not only show a dragon can be killed, but then show all the killed soldiers to be rezzed up again which they made no attempt to do so.  This is merely speculation but I would say it is safe to assume dragon fire does kill them until proven otherwise.

Comment: @ggiaquin wights and white walkers are not the same. IIRC there were no white walkers that were burned by dragon fire during the ice lake battle.

Comment: @Erich good point I didn't catch that distinction that it was about white walkers specifically.

Comment: @Erich, but NK stepped on fire 'caused by a dragon, and fire went off.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this other question here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/35176/how-useful-are-dragon-glass-arrow-heads-when-fighting-the-white-walkers-in-game?rq=1) it seems likely that dragon fire could also kill White Walkers. It cites:

> “Dragonglass.” The red woman’s laugh was music. “Frozen fire, in the tongue of old Valyria. Small wonder it is anathema to these cold children of the Other.
>
> **A Storm of Swords**

This would suggest that, because the glass is related to dragons (in the lore at least) it can kill Walkers. It would be easy to assume "unfrozen" dragon fire would have a similar killing effect.